# Displaying an icon in the ListView column

Tags: c#, wpf

This answer shows how to make ListView display and icon and some text alongside it:

[WPF - Create a listview with icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773179/wpf-create-a-listview-with-icons)

But the icon is not in its own column. I want an icon column and a text column. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not show how your `ListView` looks like so I'll assume it's very similar to that other question. You need to set `ListView.View` and specify columns. One, with your template, for image and another for text:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Template">
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=Icon, Converter={StaticResource Conv}}" Width="64" Height="64"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Icon" CellTemplate="{StaticResource Template}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Text" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```